# Change Width of text box in edit form

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, javascript, css

To improvement design of my app on sharepoint SP2013, I need change (in my case reduce) the width of text box of new form, how do it!? some idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please insert a Script editor on the page and put the below code in it :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[title = 'Title of your column']").css('width', '200px');
});
</script>
```

You can check the internal title of column by pressing F12 and then target the box.

I hope this helps !!!

Comment: @Eduardo Freitas Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted , Thanks!